# emulator problem:wipe all user data in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I faced following pop up window message problem:
Are you sure you want to wipe all user data when starting this emulator?yes or no
after this pop up window following message in console:

```
    [2011-08-28 14:46:30 - SightWords] Android Launch!
    [2011-08-28 14:46:30 - SightWords] adb is running normally.
    [2011-08-28 14:46:30 - SightWords] Performing com.horror.android.SplashScreen activity launch
    [2011-08-28 14:46:30 - SightWords] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'AndroidWQVGA400' is not available. Launching new emulator.
    [2011-08-28 14:46:30 - SightWords] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AndroidWQVGA400'
```

if click yes or no then following message add into console below the above message:

```
     [2011-08-28 14:45:14 - Emulator] invalid command-line parameter: partition-size.
     [2011-08-28 14:45:14 - Emulator] Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
     [2011-08-28 14:45:14 - Emulator] please use -help for more information
```

**Edit:** I faced this pop up message each time when new emulator run.

please fix the my error. thanks in advane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the path of the SDK your path is **Program Files\Android\android-sdk-tools/**. put SDK directly in the drive ie. **d:\Android\android-sdk-tools**

note: also remove spaces from the path by renaming the folder name

Comment: I have already set SDK path drive is  **D:\Android\android-sdk-tools**.

Comment: what partition size you are giving?

Comment: no no, i am not asking about that, what are writing in command line to open emulator?

Answer (score 3):

You are getting that pop-up because you have the option to wipe user data option selected for your project.

To turn it off, go to **Run -> Run Configurations**... When the Run Configurations window comes up, choose your Android application if necessary. Then go to the Target tab. Scroll down and you'll see a check box that says, "Wipe User Data." Uncheck that box, and you will not see that pop up again.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your Eclipse --> Window --> Android Virtual Device Manager --> Select your virtual device and click Start 
There's an option called Wipe Data for you to clear all user data